# Firebird 2.5 Events "error writing data to the connection"

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am using the latest `Firebird 2.5.3` on OSX10.10 using the C api, and have an issued I've narrowed specifically to events. I get

```
"error writing data to the connection"
```

with ~1:5 probability of happening on an event that is run from a database trigger using:

```
POST_EVENT 'xxx';
```

where 'xxx' is the Event_Callback

Is this an issue others are seeing? I'm having a hard time tracking much info down using google, as most references are for earlier versions of Firebird, or for supposedly 'fixed' bugs.

**edit - additional info**

obviously, some of the details have been

The trigger is created with something akin to:

```
"CREATE TRIGGER \"%s\" FOR \"%s\"   \
                AFTER %s                        \
             AS                                 \
              BEGIN                             \
                if( new.id = %d ) THEN          \
                    BEGIN                       \
                        INSERT INTO \"Event_Log\" (\"ID\",\"triggerName\", \"lastModified\") VALUES (GEN_ID(\"seq_Event_Table\",1)'%s', (select current_timestamp from rdb$database) );    \
                        POST_EVENT '%s';        \
                    END                         \
              END;"
```

Events are initialized with code that executes:

```
  isc_que_events(status, &database, &eventData->id, eventData->length, eventData->buffer, (isc_callback)EventCallback, eventData->resultBuffer);
```

And finally the event is structured:

```
    isc_callback EventCallback( char *result, short length, char *updated )
{
    uint64_t startTime;
    startTime = mach_absolute_time();
    printf("__EVENT__:%s:%s:%llu\n",eventData->buffer,eventData->resultBuffer,startTime);

    while (length--)
    {
        *result++ = *updated++;
    }

    isc_event_counts(status, eventData->length, eventData->buffer, eventData->resultBuffer);

    isc_que_events(status, &database, &eventData->id, eventData->length, eventData->buffer, (isc_callback)EventCallback, eventData->resultBuffer);
    return(0);
}
```

Finally, the code is tested by repeatedly tripping the trigger in a test suite similar to:

```
query = "UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1 WHERE some_column=some_value;";
for (int i=0 ; i<1e6 ; i++)
{
if (isc_start_transaction(status_vector, &transactionHandle, 1, &database, 0, NULL))                      
    {
        /*error handling*/
    }

if (isc_dsql_execute_immediate(status_vector, &database, &transactionHandle, 0, query, 3, NULL))
    {
        /*error handling*/
    }

if (isc_commit_transaction(status_vector, &transactionHandle))
    {
        /*error handling*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the C code you use to setup and queue the event callback.

Comment: This doesn't include the initialization of the eventblocks. You might want to consider posting this to the firebird-support mailinglist (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ for details), you'd get more eyes intimately familiar with the C-api.